# Vector Exam problem

Tags: vectors

After studying vectors we were given a sheet with questions to practice for exams. There is one question which I don't understand how they got that answer.

Question : Consider the plane with equation 4x-2y-z=1 and the line given by the parametric equations

x = 3-2t

y = (2k-1)+t

z = -1+kt

Given that the line is perpendicular to the plane, find 
a) the value of k ;

Any help in advance would be appreciated thanks.

The answer is K = 1/2 if you want to check if you solved it correctly.

Comment: Do you know that the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ has a normal vector $(a,b,c)$?

Comment: Yes the normal vector for the plane being ( 4, -2, -1)

Comment: So if your line is perpendicular to the plane then direction vector $(-2,1,k)$ of your line must also be perpendicular to plane, right?

Comment: Yes, can i then  use the dot product for the normal vector (dot) direction vector is = 0 ??

Comment: No, a "normal vector" is a vector which is "perpendicular" to your plane. If normal vector (dot) direction vector equals $0$ you actually have your line "parallel" to the plane. So you actually want your direction vector to be parallel to your normal vector.

Comment: Ahh I see, so what about using normal vector (dot) direction vector = 1? Wouldn't that have the line perpendicular to the plane then :O

Comment: Not really, dot product equals $1$ doesn't necessarily mean they are parallel. There is much easier condition for being parallel vectors which to just say that they are multiples of each other

Comment: Okay, well comparing the two vectors I see multiples of -1/2, but the answer is 1/2 so how come the negative isn't there

Comment: You probably made a mistake in your calculation. You have $(4,-2,-1)=\lambda(-2,1,k)$, and comparing components you see $\lambda=-2$. So $-2k=-1$, where you get $k=1/2$

Comment: Yeh my bad, Thanks a lot for the help. Cleared it for me :)